# How do I use the .done() callback to run a function for new data being loaded on request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page displaying data from a json feed and I also have a button which loads more of the feed on click of a button. My aim is to append some content inside the page for each feed item. I have been able to create a function which does this on load of the page, but I am unsure how to make this work with the aysynchronous loading of more data.

I understand I need to use the `.done()` callback to make this work but need some guidance how to implement it correctly.

This function appends the new content initially:

```
function appendFeed() {
$('.feed__item').each(function (index) {
$feedItem = $('.feed__item', $(this));
$feedItem.append('<div class="feed-gallery"></div>');

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
var $count = i;
if ($count > 1) {
$('.feed.gallery', $(this)).append('<div><img data-lazy="//placehold.it/50x50"></div>');
};
});
}
```

This is where the `.done()` callback is referred, on click of a button:

```
$('button').click(function(){
        $.getJSON(uri, function (json, textStatus) {
          // do stuff
        }).done(function (json) {
         // do stuff - in my case this would be appendFeed() 
        });
});
```

I have already called the `appendFeed()` function, but if I put it inside the `.done()` callback on click the button, then it appends the feed again. How do i prevent the duplication for the feed that is already on the page?

Comment: What exactly is it that's not clear? It's a function and you put code in it.

Comment: @Pointy, if i put the function inside the .done() callback, it will append twice for the feed that is already initially loaded on the page.

Comment: @zxynz You must call the function only on the new elements. If you can show us that function we might be able to advise you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will write.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $.getJSON("/waqar/file.php").done(function (data) {
        $(".output").append(data);
      });
    </script>
```